# AWS S3 Access Denied when open object URL in browser

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am new to aws..
I uploaded a image in the bucket

if i try to open the object url in browser im getting the following error.

[image]

below are the bucket policies i have configured my bucket with

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1566555268319",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1566555264845",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::497899159094:user/DevUser"
            },
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::akirainfocombucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:x-amz-acl": "public-read"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

and Below are the CORS Configurations

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>POST</AllowedMethod>
    <AllowedMethod>PUT</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

The Block all public access is set to Off as suggested by the support team.

I want the object link to be accessible in the browser..(Read only)

need help to configure the Bucket ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I doubted this might need permission to get the object so that you can view the image from the URL in S3.

I configured the bucket policy like given below.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "AddPerm",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:PutObjectAcl",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::delxpro.com/*"
    }
]
}
```

In the above code, look for this piece of line **"s3:GetObject"**.
Add this line in your action attribute and check will it work or not.

It will retrieves object from S3, so that you can view your image from the URL.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the problem, in your bucket policies you only allow put and you are not allowing read access:

"Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:PutObjectAcl"
            ],